# Find percentage of two small numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two small numbers that I'd like to find the percentage of.

```
First number: 0.683789473684211
Second number: 0.678958333333333
```

I want to find out what percentage of the number is bigger or smaller. These happen to be small numbers, but they could be bigger. The first number COULD be 250, and the second number could be 0.3443435. What I'm TRYING to do is detect whether the first number is 25% bigger than the second number.

I tried using this:

```
class Numeric
  def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.0
  end
end
```

But it kept saying I was dividing by zero

How would you do it?

Comment: In pseudo-code: would `if a > (b*1.25) then // do something` do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Why not shoot straight for what you say you want to do?

```
class Numeric
  def sufficiently_bigger?(n, proportion = 1.25)
    self >= proportion * n
  end
end

p 5.sufficiently_bigger? 4          # => true
p 5.sufficiently_bigger? 4.00001    # => false
```

This will default to a 25% larger check, but you can override the proportionality by supplying a different value as the second argument.

It's generally easier and avoids the need for an explicit zero-denominator check if you express ratios in product form rather than using division.

Answer (score 0):

The basic implementation of your code looks correct to me. Can you provide the specific example and expected output that is producing that error?

Just because I was curious I took your code and executed it with a small test suite and had 3 passing tests.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'

class Numeric
  def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.00
  end
end

class PercentageTeset < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_25_is_50_percent_of_50
    assert_equal (25.percent_of(50)), 50.0
  end 
  def test_50_is_100_percent_of_50
    assert_equal (50.percent_of(50)), 100.0
  end
  def test_75_is_150_percent_of_50
    assert_equal (75.percent_of(50)), 150.0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Numeric
  def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.0
  end
end

p 0.683789473684211.percent_of(0.678958333333333)

--output:--
100.71155181602376

p 250.percent_of(0.3443435)

--output:--
72601.9222084924

p 0.000_001.percent_of(0.000_000_5)

--output:--
200.0

p 0.000_000_000_01.percent_of(0.000_000_000_01)

--output:--
100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Numeric
  def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.0
  end
end

numbers = [ 0.683789473684211, 0.678958333333333 ]
min_max = {min: numbers.min, max: numbers.max}

puts "%<min>f is #{min_max[:min].percent_of(min_max[:max])} of %<max>f" % min_max
```

This program has opinions in that it shows what percentage the minimal number is of the maximal number, and shows the numbers.

If you use `%d` for the `String#format` method, you will show 0's.  Perhaps that was what you were referring to, not sure.

Edit: Using minmax as suggested.

```
class Numeric
  def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.0
  end
end

numbers = [ 0.683789473684211, 0.678958333333333 ]
min_max = Hash.new
min_max[:min], min_max[:max] = numbers.minmax

puts "%<min>f is #{min_max[:min].percent_of(min_max[:max])} of %<max>f" % min_max
```

I like the first version as the hash is built as it is needed, rather than initalized and then built.

Comment: [minmax](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) is an existing method in Enumerable.